# Location based services - protocol

Tags: location

I am interested in deploying cloud service for video survilience  like ezviz or ivideon. On the hikvision camera I found LBS server settings that point to ezviz servers.

I changed LBS to my server,hoping that camera should start sending me all its information.
Does anyone know which protocol they use? I thought that it may be http but there is nothing I can find in wireshark. There is only TCP packets go back and forth with not understandable data in it.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I probably use HTTP, but I found a protocol for live video streaming, it's call RTP. Good Luck

Comment: I am asking about exchange protocol for LBS Services.